# Edittext cuts text with center and left align spans

Tags: android

in my app I use 3 AlignmentSpan.Standard: center, normal, opposite. To keep it simple lets name these paragraphs like: paragraph with left align - first paragraph, paragraph with central align - second paragraph, paragraph with right align - third paragraph.

For example user creates 3 paragraph. After that user use LeadingMarginSpan.Standard for second paragraph to get a indent. When indent applyed, first paragraph moves out from EditText for certain amount of px  and second paragraph visible stay at center.

When user tap at first paragraph everything is ok, all paragraphs stay at required position and second paragraph stay with indent. If tap at second paragraph all paragraph will move to left side

Code:

```
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    et.setText("ab\nab\nab");
    AlignmentSpan.Standard normal = new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL);
    AlignmentSpan.Standard center = new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
    AlignmentSpan.Standard opposite = new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE);
    et.getEditableText().setSpan(normal, 0, 3, Spanned.SPAN_PARAGRAPH);
    et.getEditableText().setSpan(center, 3, 6, Spanned.SPAN_PARAGRAPH);
    et.getEditableText().setSpan(opposite, 6, et.length(), Spanned.SPAN_PARAGRAPH);
    LeadingMarginSpan.Standard indent = new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(20);
    et.getEditableText().setSpan(indent, 3,6, Spanned.SPAN_PARAGRAPH);
```

Select first align:
[image]
Select second align:
[image]

Edit:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea9HJEmEeZA&feature=youtu.be

Comment: little bit confusing question anna, can you please explain me in simple language?

Comment: I added video, to show how it work and update the question

Comment: ok got it, good question. Need to check for this

Comment: found something or not?